# How to clear the *Backtrace* buffer in emacs

Tags: emacs

How to delete all the error messages in the *Backtrace* buffer, so that when a new error occurs only the new error will be displayed instead of prepending with the old error.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The backtrace buffer has its own mode with several command shortcuts. I use the 'q' key to kill the buffer and continue on but I'm sure others will work as well.

Here's a list of them: http://www.cs.utah.edu/dept/old/texinfo/emacs18/emacs_26.html#SEC190

Comment: Link is broken.